# Is it wrong to store DataTable in Cache?

Tags: asp.net, caching, serialization, datatable

I've seen numerous examples of people storing DataTables into the Cache, but I am just wondering, do the same rules apply to the Cache that apply to the Session? The one rule I am most concerned with is:

Do not store unserializable objects into the Session. Just because you can doesn't mean it is guaranteed to work (I learned this the hard way).

So ultimately my question is:

Can you store unserializable objects into the Cache?

I reasearched this for a while, reading numerous posts and even reading the chapter about Cache in my ASP.NET 3.5 book and I cannot find it anywhere.

Since I am in doubt, I am going to put my DataTable into a DataSet then into the Cache, but is this necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cache is always using the machine's memory, the Session uses what has been configured:

In a web farm the Session can be local (which works only if affinity is set), or remote (state server or database, or custom), but the cache is always local.

So, storing a DataTable in the cache will consume memory, but it will not use serialization.

PS: storing a DataSet instead of a DataTable will change almost nothing.

Comment: +1 for "storing a DataSet instead of a DataTable will change almost nothing"

Comment: Thank you for your reply and clearing that up for me. Here is a related question. Is it frowned upon to store data in a Cache variable like so: "Cache[Session.SessionID + "variableName"] = object". The goal being here to avoid storing unserializable objects in the session (I am using SQL Server for my Session Management), but also avoid more than one session manipulating that object. Is this a bad practice?

Comment: @dyslexicanaboko - The cache is only for quick access to a data that's actually stored *elsewhere*. It should never be the sole storage for a given data. Why? because it can be emptied anytime by ASP.NET for some reason (too much memory, cpu, etc...). Cache access should always be in the form: if (data not in cache) then (read data from storage, cache it, return it).

Comment: In my case I am using it for paging, so more often than not the data will be changed anyhow if the user searches for something different than what they are looking at - at that time. Thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 3):

A DataTable IS serializable so the concern doesn't apply in this case...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(VS.71).aspx

from the top of the page linked to above:

```
[Visual Basic]
<Serializable>
Public Class DataTable
   Inherits MarshalByValueComponent
   Implements IListSource, ISupportInitialize, ISerializable
[C#]
[Serializable]
public class DataTable : MarshalByValueComponent, IListSource,
   ISupportInitialize, ISerializable
```

I've used them in cache without problem many times.  From my experience, the bigger concern is the amount of data in the cache.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't look that up... I have to show this to one of my co-workers so we don't have this argument anymore. I was under the impression it wasn't serializable because a co-worker of mine told me it wasn't, but I should have looked it up. Thanks for setting me straight on that.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the Cache and the Session is that the Cache is public for the application that means the Cache is visible to all the users logged in to the application, but for the Session every user has its own instance of the Session and thus data cached in the session will not be visible among multiple users.

You use Cache usually to store files, data result sets, objects... that are not changed frequently, heavy to load or calculate and requested very often that way you enhance the application performance.

Finally, yes you can store unserializable objects in the Cache.

Comment: I learned that recently because I don't often store things in the Session or in the Cache because my superiors get all pissy when I do. Obviously it is unavoidable in certain cases to not use the Session or the Cache, but I made a big mistake thinking that the Cache was not application wide, I figured that out while debugging something that wasn't working well.